# Is there a C++ implementation for vEB Trees?

Tags: c++, data-structures, van-emde-boas-trees

Is there a reliable C++ implementation of [vEB Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree)?

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) doesn't have it. It seems quite unusual.

Are there any (maybe commercial) libraries for vEB Trees or y-fast tries or similar data structures?

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be a [C implementation](http://code.google.com/p/libveb/)...