# C++ Floating-Point van Emde Boas (vEB) Priority Queue

Tags: c++, templates, tree

So [van Emde Boas trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) look like they have some very nice properties.

I'd like to try using one as the underlying data structure for a floating-point priority queue.

Does anyone know if there is a C++ template-based implementation of the vEB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a C++ implementation for vEB Trees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714516/is-there-a-c-implementation-for-veb-trees)

Comment: Definitely worth linking, though it would need some wrapping to provide the safety of a C++ template implementation.

Comment: The floating-point bit is also not guaranteed by the link, but thanks so much for it - I'll add vEB to the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds unpleasant -- the vEB tree is a mapping from an integer to a value (or from an integer to a present bit).  If you want to index it with a floating point value, you'll have to convert it to an integer in a way that preserves ordering.  This is doable, but not necessarily pleasant -- you have to deal with denormals and signed zeroes.

What are you trying to do?  A different data structure might be a win.  vEB trees need to get rather large before they'll outperform simple things like binary heaps.